# How do I set the window / screen size in xna?

Tags: xna, fullscreen

How can I adjust the size of the window in XNA.

Default it starts in a 800x600 resolution.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I found out that you need to set the

```cs
GraphicDevice.PreferredBackBufferHeight = height;
GraphicDevice.PreferredBackBufferWidth = width;
```

When you do this in the constructor of the game class it works, but when you try do to this outside the constructor you also need to call

```cs
GraphicsDevice.ApplyChanges();
```

Furthermore to have fullscreen (which is not really working correctly while debugging) you can use

```cs
if (!GraphicsDevice.IsFullScreen)
   GraphicsDevice.ToggleFullScreen();
```

Comment: This answer is a bit out of date, so I recommend checking Fuex's answer below. It is mostly the same but the code will compile without any edits.

Answer (score 71):

As of XNA 4.0 this property is now found on the `GraphicsDeviceManager`.
Ie. this code would go in your Game's constructor.

```cs
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 340;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 480;

// if changing GraphicsDeviceManager properties outside 
// your game constructor also call:
// graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

Comment: Sjors Miltenburg's answer below is now out of date. This answer by Fuex is proper for XNA 4.0.

Comment: You will still want to do graphics.ApplyChanges() after this, though.

Answer (score -1):

This solution works in XNA 3.0.  Just put it in your game object's constructor:

```cs
// Resize the screen to 1024 x 768.
IntPtr ptr = this.Window.Handle;
System.Windows.Forms.Form form = (System.Windows.Forms.Form)System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromHandle(ptr);
form.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 768);

graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;

graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

Answer (score -2):

You should look at this, http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/1031/107718.aspx.