# XNA Changing window size not working

Tags: c#, xna

I tried changing the size of the window according to this:

[How do I set the window / screen size in xna?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720429/how-do-i-set-the-window-screen-size-in-xna)

however, it doesn't seem to have any affect.

```
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 300;
    graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;
```

I put that in the constructor. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are only setting the height, set the width too

> **graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth** = 300;
>
> graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;

Comment: Wow what happened was it was meant to be width for the second value but and so the height kept reverting to its default value (500).