# XNA-How do I set the resolution in a winfows forum?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, xna

I want to use a win form. For some reason I'm not able to keep the resolution when I show a new dialog in my game class so I just want to use my win form as my main on launch but now I need to set the users resolution to 1024x768.

Setting the form itself is easy but, I need to set the user's resolution so that it matches the form.

How can I do that?

Comment: What? Is this what you mean: [How do I set the Window / Screen Size in XNA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720429/how-do-i-set-the-window-screen-size-in-xna)?

Comment: Does not work when you use a winforum

Comment: Don't ever change the desktop resolution of a user programmatically! They will kill you. If you really can't find a different solution (if you describe your problem a bit more detailed, one could help you with that), I'd propose to use a RenderTarget of 1024x768 size, render everything into it and then render everything from the RT to the backbuffer (stretched). Will be quite ugly though, probably.